# How do I create a function that changes data on page so I don't have to create multiple different pages for each stall

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to create multiple files for different stalls but it seems so wrong and I know there's a better way but I just don't know how. Is there a way to create something like a page builder that will let me create multiple pages with different information from a single file. The difficult part is to make the `onTap` function of the images send the user to the `stall_page` of the selected stall. I tried doing this by making a `view` attribute in which I create a page and manually import the page route. But that involves creating a `stall_info` and `stall_page` for every single stall.

Instead of creating stall1_page, stall2_page and so on, can I create a generic stall function that will use the same page but just change the data? I know that's LITERALLY the point of object oriented programming languages but I'm really new to them as you'll tell my previous stupid questions.

This is the homescreen dashboard

```
class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  Item item1 = Item(
    title: 'Tray blazers',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: 'by Chef Tracy',
    img: 'assets/images/tray_blazers-cr.png',
    view: stallPage,
  );

  Item item2 = Item(
    title: 'Papa Rimz',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/papa_rimz.png',
    view: papaRimzPage,
  );

  Item item3 = Item(
    title: 'W SAUCE',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/w_sauce-removebg.png',
    view: wSaucePage,
  );

  Item item4 = Item(
    title: 'African Kitchen',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/cherry-kitchen.png',
    view: africanKitchenPage,
  );

  Item item5 = Item(
    title: 'Suya Craze',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/suya_craze.png',
    view: suyaCrazePage,
  );

  Item item6 = Item(
    title: 'Zulkys cafe',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/zulkys-removeb.png',
    view: zulkysCafePage,
  );

  Item item7 = Item(
    title: 'Street food',
    subtitle: 'Open',
    event: '',
    img: 'assets/images/street_food--removebg-.png',
    view: streetFoodPage,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Item> myList = [
      item1,
      item2,
      item3,
      item4,
      item5,
      item6,
      item7,
    ];

    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 18,
        mainAxisSpacing: 18,
        children: myList.map(
          (data) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xff453658),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(data.view);
                    },
                    child: Image.asset(
                      data.img,
                      width: 90, //double.infinity
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 14),
                  Text(
                    data.title,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 13,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  Text(
                    data.subtitle,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      color: Colors.white38,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 8),
                  // Text(
                  //   data.event,
                  //   style: const TextStyle(
                  //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  //     fontSize: 11,
                  //     color: Colors.white70,
                  //   ),
                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  String event;
  String img;
  String view;
  Item({
    required this.title,
    required this.subtitle,
    required this.event,
    required this.img,
    required this.view,
  });
}
```

This is my stall_page:

```
class StallPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const StallPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StallPage> createState() => _StallPageState();
}

class _StallPageState extends State<StallPage> {
  var selected = 0;
  final pageController = PageController();
  final stall = Stall.generateRestaurant1();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff392850), //kBackground,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          CustomAppBar(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            Icons.search_outlined,
            leftCallback: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          StallInfo(), //
          FoodList(
            selected,
            (int index) {
              setState(() {
                selected = index;
              });
              pageController.jumpToPage(index);
            },
            stall,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FoodListView(
              selected,
              (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = index;
                });
              },
              pageController,
              stall,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
            height: 60,
            child: SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: pageController,
              count: stall.menu.length,
              effect: CustomizableEffect(
                dotDecoration: DotDecoration(
                  width: 8,
                  height: 8,
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                activeDotDecoration: DotDecoration(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  color: kBackground,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  dotBorder: const DotBorder(
                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                    padding: 2,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onDotClicked: (index) => pageController.jumpToPage(index),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        elevation: 2,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my stall_info

```
class StallInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  final stall = Stall.generateRestaurant1();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    stall.name,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.4),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            stall.label,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                child: Image.asset(
                  stall.logoUrl,
                  width: 80,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                stall.desc,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.star_outline,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${stall.score}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 15),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is stall

```
class Stall {
  String name;
  String label;
  String logoUrl;
  String desc;
  num score;
  Map<String, List<Food>> menu;
  Stall(
    this.name,
    this.label,
    this.logoUrl,
    this.desc,
    this.score,
    this.menu,
  );
  static Stall generateRestaurant1() {
    return Stall(
      'Tray blazers',
      'Restaurant',
      'assets/images/tray_blazers.jpg',
      'Tray Blazers by Chef Tracy',
      4.5,
      {
        'Recommended': Food.generateRecommendedFoods1(),
        'Popular': Food.generatePopularFoods1(),
        'Smoothie': [],
        'Rice': [],
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to open the `StallPage` but show different values on the page depending on which image (pertaining to a given 'Stall') was selected on the previous page? I.e. clicking on `item2` should open the `StallPage` with the restaurant title "Papa Rimz" etc.?

In that case, you can pass the argument to your new route builder via the `onTap()` function as a constructor parameter instead of calling `Stall.generateRestaurant1()` with hardcoded values in a given dart file.

### StallInfo

Instead of getting your stall data inside the build method, you simply accept it as a required parameter for your widget. Now you have access to the data (title, ...) anywhere inside here.

```
class StallInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  // Contains the stall object with its name, label, menu etc.
  final Stall stall;

  StallInfo({super.key, required this.stall});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
      child: Column(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### HomeScreen

I'm a bit confused as to what the item list in your your home screen is for. Are these food items in a restaurant? Because if so, I think it would be much easier to save them inside the stall as a list of items and then use that list here:

```
List<Stall> _stalls = [...];
```

I'd like to note here that you hardcoded all the items by name and then, in your build method, added them to a list. Since you don't need their names anywhere, it would be just a little bit better to move the `List<Stall> myList` outside the build method and simply assign the objects directly (that is, before you add a real database):

```
class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {

    List<Stall> _stalls = [
       Stall('Tray blazers', ...),
       Stall('Papa Rimz', ...),
    ];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     // do something with your stalls, onTap, pass the element directly
      ....
      children: _stalls.map(
       (data) {
         return GestureDetector(
           onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => StallPage(stall: data)
               ));
           }
         );
       }),
    } 


}
```

If you use a builder function for your GridView (which you should if there can be a lot of stalls), in the `onTap()` you can instead call:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => StallPage(stall: _stalls.elementAt(index))
));
```

### StallPage

This page will look something like this

```
class StallPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final Stall stall; // Take in the stall you passed from your home screen

  const StallPage({super.key, required this.stall});

  @override
  State<StallPage> createState() => _StallPageState();
}

class _StallPageState extends State<StallPage> {
  var selected = 0;
  final pageController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       ...
       StallInfo(stall: widget.stall), // This is how you can access the values passed inside a StatefulWidget
       ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I'd literally marry you if I could. This is perfect! Thanks a whole lot for taking your time to craft this lengthy answer to explain it to my smooth brain. P.S thanks again